# Filtering, sorting, and drilling in SSRS 2005 reports

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I have sucessfully deployed Cube in [SSRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services) 2005. How do I perform drilling, filtering, sorting, etc.? What are the ways to do this?